# How do I make a local variable in another function usable?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Right now I want my instantiated bullet to destroy when it collides with a wall, but Visual Studio says that 'bullet' does not exist in the current context in the OnTriggerEnter2D function.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
namespace work.working.worked
{
    public class Shooting : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public static bool firing;
        public Transform firepoint;
        public GameObject bulletprefab;
        public float bulletspeed;
        // Update is called once per frame
        void Update()
        {
            if (firing == false)
            {
                if (Movement.ismoving == false)
                {
                    firing = true;
                    StartCoroutine(Shoot());
                }
            }
        }
        IEnumerator Shoot()
        {
            GameObject bullet = Instantiate(bulletprefab, firepoint.position, firepoint.rotation);
            Rigidbody2D rb = bullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
            rb.AddForce(firepoint.up * bulletspeed, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);
            firing = false;
        }
        private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
        {
            Destroy(bullet);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to use it elsewhere, it shouldn't be local variable.

Comment: It won't do what you want anyway since you want to destroy the bullet **when the bullet collides**, not when **this object** that spawns the bullet collides ... => Put a dedicated component on the bullet prefab that tracks the `OnTriggerEnter` ...

Answer (score -1):

You can't do that, and you can't change the method signature and pass the variable as a method argument because it's an unity event function so it must stay how it is. Instead, turn it into a field.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
namespace work.working.worked
{
    public class Shooting : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public static bool firing;
        public Transform firepoint;
        public GameObject bulletprefab;
        public float bulletspeed;
    private GameObject bullet;
        // Update is called once per frame
        void Update()
        {
            if (firing == false)
            {
                if (Movement.ismoving == false)
                {
                    firing = true;
                    StartCoroutine(Shoot());
                }
            }
        }
        IEnumerator Shoot()
        {
            bullet = Instantiate(bulletprefab, firepoint.position, firepoint.rotation);
            Rigidbody2D rb = bullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
            rb.AddForce(firepoint.up * bulletspeed, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);
            firing = false;
        }
        private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
        {
            Destroy(bullet);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I made bullet into a field here instead of it being a local variable. This is what you gotta do.

Comment: for some reason, the bullet doesn't destroy when colliding

Comment: Make sure both the bullet and the colliding object have collider, and the collider on the bullet has the "isTrigger" box checked.

Comment: My man you are a lifesaver. I want you to remember that before you go to bed every night knowing you have solved a problem a random person on the internet had for over 2 days.